# Signal when 3 BOS or CHoCH one after the other have been detected

Tags: pine-script

First of all I have just started with pinescript as my first coding experience ever. I am using a free open source code for smart money concepts and want to add an alarm when the following condition has been met:

1st Bear BOS, 2nd Bull iCHoCH and 3rd Bear iCHoCH as per the attachment:

https://www.tradingview.com/x/hbIJIqo7/

The source code is Lux Algo smart money concept(free version).

Thanks,
A

I want to make a strategy and for me its only when I have either 3 BOS or 3 CHoCH in a certain direction that I would like to trade. Of course I use other  indicators as confluence but I do not want to spend so much time on the charts that's why I want this alarm.

Thanks

Comment: After the first paragraph, I first thought you'd switched into a foreign language .  Even though you do switch back to English before the end, it's still not clear what you are asking ? But Googling for Lux Algo Smart Money helped me because the first link explains what your funny words mean!  BOS = Break of Structure, Change of Character (CHoCH) - although not a bear or bull one.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to 1) modify this script to add some new functionality that it didn't do before? Or are you trying to 2) just use the script to create these rules using its settings & filters for confluences & swings, etc? Or are you trying to do the second option, but intercept the data to sound an alarm instead of drawing a chart?

Comment: Woow, that was some quick replying :). I have just refreshed my page and seen your answer. I want to modify the script so that I can set an alarm on what is already a great script. The script has a lot more function then what  I need. So I need to use what's already written to add more confluence. I want an alarm after the charts draws the CH0CH and the BOS's. My condition being the ones in the link. So second option. English is not my first language anyway but hope you understood what I meant :)

Comment: Sorry I am new to Stack, think I posted an answer and it was not suppose to be answer but rather a clarification to question from Noscere confirming that is the script I was talking about. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Is this the script you are referring? The one at [tradingview.com](https://www.tradingview.com/script/CnB3fSph-Smart-Money-Concepts-LUX/) on a page about Smart Money Concepts-LUX

```
// This work is licensed under a Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0) https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/
// © LuxAlgo

//@version=5
indicator("Smart Money Concepts [LUX]", "Smart Money Concepts [LuxAlgo]"
  , overlay = true
  , max_labels_count = 500
  , max_lines_count = 500
  , max_boxes_count = 500
  , max_bars_back = 500)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Constants
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
color TRANSP_CSS = #ffffff00

//Tooltips
string MODE_TOOLTIP          = 'Allows to display historical Structure or only the recent ones'
string STYLE_TOOLTIP         = 'Indicator color theme'
string COLOR_CANDLES_TOOLTIP = 'Display additional candles with a color reflecting the current trend detected by structure'
string SHOW_INTERNAL         = 'Display internal market structure'
string CONFLUENCE_FILTER     = 'Filter non significant internal structure breakouts'
string SHOW_SWING            = 'Display swing market Structure'
string SHOW_SWING_POINTS     = 'Display swing point as labels on the chart'
string SHOW_SWHL_POINTS      = 'Highlight most recent strong and weak high/low points on the chart'
string INTERNAL_OB           = 'Display internal order blocks on the chart\n\nNumber of internal order blocks to display on the chart'
string SWING_OB              = 'Display swing order blocks on the chart\n\nNumber of internal swing blocks to display on the chart'
string FILTER_OB             = 'Method used to filter out volatile order blocks \n\nIt is recommended to use the cumulative mean range method when a low amount of data is available'
string SHOW_EQHL             = 'Display equal highs and equal lows on the chart'
string EQHL_BARS             = 'Number of bars used to confirm equal highs and equal lows'
string EQHL_THRESHOLD        = 'Sensitivity threshold in a range (0, 1) used for the detection of equal highs & lows\n\nLower values will return fewer but more pertinent results'
string SHOW_FVG              = 'Display fair values gaps on the chart'
string AUTO_FVG              = 'Filter out non significant fair value gaps'
string FVG_TF                = 'Fair value gaps timeframe'
string EXTEND_FVG            = 'Determine how many bars to extend the Fair Value Gap boxes on chart'
string PED_ZONES             = 'Display premium, discount, and equilibrium zones on chart'

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//General
//----------------------------------------{
mode = input.string('Historical'
  , options = ['Historical', 'Present']
  , group = 'Smart Money Concepts'
  , tooltip = MODE_TOOLTIP)

style = input.string('Colored'
  , options = ['Colored', 'Monochrome']
  , group = 'Smart Money Concepts'
  , tooltip = STYLE_TOOLTIP)

show_trend = input(false, 'Color Candles'
  , group = 'Smart Money Concepts'
  , tooltip = COLOR_CANDLES_TOOLTIP)

//----------------------------------------}
//Internal Structure
//----------------------------------------{
show_internals = input(true, 'Show Internal Structure'
  , group = 'Real Time Internal Structure'
  , tooltip = SHOW_INTERNAL)

show_ibull = input.string('All', 'Bullish Structure'
  , options = ['All', 'BOS', 'CHoCH']
  , inline = 'ibull'
  , group = 'Real Time Internal Structure')

swing_ibull_css = input(#089981, ''
  , inline = 'ibull'
  , group = 'Real Time Internal Structure')

//Bear Structure
show_ibear = input.string('All', 'Bearish Structure'
  , options = ['All', 'BOS', 'CHoCH']
  , inline = 'ibear'
  , group = 'Real Time Internal Structure')

swing_ibear_css = input(#f23645, ''
  , inline = 'ibear'
  , group = 'Real Time Internal Structure')

ifilter_confluence = input(false, 'Confluence Filter'
  , group = 'Real Time Internal Structure'
  , tooltip = CONFLUENCE_FILTER)

//----------------------------------------}
//Swing Structure
//----------------------------------------{
show_Structure = input(true, 'Show Swing Structure'
  , group = 'Real Time Swing Structure'
  , tooltip = SHOW_SWING)

//Bull Structure
show_bull = input.string('All', 'Bullish Structure'
  , options = ['All', 'BOS', 'CHoCH']
  , inline = 'bull'
  , group = 'Real Time Swing Structure')

swing_bull_css = input(#089981, ''
  , inline = 'bull'
  , group = 'Real Time Swing Structure')

//Bear Structure
show_bear = input.string('All', 'Bearish Structure'
  , options = ['All', 'BOS', 'CHoCH']
  , inline = 'bear'
  , group = 'Real Time Swing Structure')

swing_bear_css = input(#f23645, ''
  , inline = 'bear'
  , group = 'Real Time Swing Structure')

//Swings
show_swings = input(false, 'Show Swings Points'
  , inline = 'swings'
  , group = 'Real Time Swing Structure'
  , tooltip = SHOW_SWING_POINTS)

length = input.int(50, ''
  , minval = 10
  , inline = 'swings'
  , group = 'Real Time Swing Structure')

show_hl_swings = input(true, 'Show Strong/Weak High/Low'
  , group = 'Real Time Swing Structure'
  , tooltip = SHOW_SWHL_POINTS)

//----------------------------------------}
//Order Blocks
//----------------------------------------{
show_iob = input(true, 'Internal Order Blocks'
  , inline = 'iob'
  , group = 'Order Blocks'
  , tooltip = INTERNAL_OB)

iob_showlast = input.int(5, ''
  , minval = 1
  , inline = 'iob'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

ob_filter = input.string('Atr', 'Order Block Filter'
  , options = ['Atr', 'Cumulative Mean Range']
  , group = 'Order Blocks'
  , tooltip = FILTER_OB)

ibull_ob_css = input.color(color.new(#3179f5, 80), 'Internal Bullish OB'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

ibear_ob_css = input.color(color.new(#f77c80, 80), 'Internal Bearish OB'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

bull_ob_css = input.color(color.new(#1848cc, 80), 'Bullish OB'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

bear_ob_css = input.color(color.new(#b22833, 80), 'Bearish OB'
  , group = 'Order Blocks')

//----------------------------------------}
//EQH/EQL
//----------------------------------------{
show_eq = input(true, 'Equal High/Low'
  , group = 'EQH/EQL'
  , tooltip = SHOW_EQHL)

eq_len = input.int(3, 'Bars Confirmation'
  , minval = 1
  , group = 'EQH/EQL'
  , tooltip = EQHL_BARS)

eq_threshold = input.float(0.1, 'Threshold'
  , minval = 0
  , maxval = 0.5
  , step = 0.1
  , group = 'EQH/EQL'
  , tooltip = EQHL_THRESHOLD)

//----------------------------------------}
//Fair Value Gaps
//----------------------------------------{
show_fvg = input(false, 'Fair Value Gaps'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps'
  , tooltip = SHOW_FVG)
  
fvg_auto = input(true, "Auto Threshold"
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps'
  , tooltip = AUTO_FVG)

fvg_tf = input.timeframe('', "Timeframe"
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps'
  , tooltip = FVG_TF)

bull_fvg_css = input.color(color.new(#00ff68, 70), 'Bullish FVG'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

bear_fvg_css = input.color(color.new(#ff0008, 70), 'Bearish FVG'
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps')

fvg_extend = input.int(1, "Extend FVG"
  , minval = 0
  , group = 'Fair Value Gaps'
  , tooltip = EXTEND_FVG)

//----------------------------------------}
//Previous day/week high/low
//----------------------------------------{
//Daily
show_pdhl = input(false, 'Daily'
  , inline = 'daily'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

pdhl_style = input.string('⎯⎯⎯', ''
  , options = ['⎯⎯⎯', '----', '····']
  , inline = 'daily'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

pdhl_css = input(#2157f3, ''
  , inline = 'daily'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

//Weekly
show_pwhl = input(false, 'Weekly'
  , inline = 'weekly'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

pwhl_style = input.string('⎯⎯⎯', ''
  , options = ['⎯⎯⎯', '----', '····']
  , inline = 'weekly'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

pwhl_css = input(#2157f3, ''
  , inline = 'weekly'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

//Monthly
show_pmhl = input(false, 'Monthly'
  , inline = 'monthly'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

pmhl_style = input.string('⎯⎯⎯', ''
  , options = ['⎯⎯⎯', '----', '····']
  , inline = 'monthly'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

pmhl_css = input(#2157f3, ''
  , inline = 'monthly'
  , group = 'Highs & Lows MTF')

//----------------------------------------}
//Premium/Discount zones
//----------------------------------------{
show_sd = input(false, 'Premium/Discount Zones'
  , group = 'Premium & Discount Zones'
  , tooltip = PED_ZONES)

premium_css = input.color(#f23645, 'Premium Zone'
  , group = 'Premium & Discount Zones')

eq_css = input.color(#b2b5be, 'Equilibrium Zone'
  , group = 'Premium & Discount Zones')

discount_css = input.color(#089981, 'Discount Zone'
  , group = 'Premium & Discount Zones')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ETC ETC Continued... couldn't paste the whole script as Stack limits posts to 30,000 lines, and this would have made my post ~32,000!
```

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Sorry Vickel, that is not the answer. I still need help but hey hot it's Christmas now....